# GLFW texture rendering issue

Tags: c, glfw

I am new with GLFW. I tried to display a texture based on a tested example code.

The example comes from: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html
That renders a rotating colorful triangle.

I modified the code based on this page: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 
#include "linmath.h"
 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"


static const struct
{
    float x, y;
    float r, g, b;
} vertices[3] =
{
    { -0.6f, -0.4f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    {  0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f },
    {   0.f,  0.6f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f }
};
 
static const char* vertex_shader_text =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;\n"
"layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;\n"
"uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
"out vec2 UV;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);\n"
"UV = vertexUV;\n"
"}\n";
 
static const char* fragment_shader_text =
"#version 330 core\n"
"in vec2 UV;\n"
"out vec3 color;\n"
"uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    color = texture(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb;\n"
"}\n";
 
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}
 
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
}

GLuint init_texture(char *imagepath)
{
    
    unsigned int width,height,nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(imagepath, &width, &height, &nrChannels, STBI_rgb_alpha); 

    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    // Read the file, call glTexImage2D with the right parameters
    //glfwLoadTexture2D(imagepath, 0);

    // Nice trilinear filtering.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    
    stbi_image_free(data);
    // Return the ID of the texture we just created
    return textureID;
}
 
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    GLuint vertex_buffer, vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
    GLint mvp_location, vpos_location, vcol_location;
 
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
 
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
 
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // NOTE: OpenGL error checks have been omitted for brevity
 
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
 
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
 
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
 
    mvp_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    vpos_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
    vcol_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vCol");
 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(vertices[0]), (void*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vcol_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vcol_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(vertices[0]), (void*) (sizeof(float) * 2));
                          
    //Load Texure
    init_texture("lara.png");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        mat4x4 m, p, mvp;
 
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
 
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 
        mat4x4_identity(m);
        mat4x4_rotate_Z(m, m, (float) glfwGetTime());
        mat4x4_ortho(p, -ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        mat4x4_mul(mvp, p, m);
 
        glUseProgram(program);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_location, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*) mvp);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
 
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
 
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I did something wrong and now I cannot render anything. I used stbi_load to load pixel data. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Learn some debugging skills: Undo the things you did (make a backup copy first so you can undo your undo) and when it starts working again, that's what you did wrong. Or, start from the version that works, and change it again, and when it stops working, that's what you did wrong.

Comment: Is the original sample your copied works as expected? Testing this is required to make sure your setup is OK. Then progressively change to code to fit your needs, checking each step. And **use a debugger**!

Comment: yes I tested the orginal source. That renders the expected triangle. When I modified the shader it went wrong. Again if I replace the shader with orginal that renders.

Comment: alright, I realized that, I put texture file to project folder not to build folder. Then I moved it to there. However, at this time I render a white triangle instead of texture.

Comment: I did it. I modified  vpos_location = glGetAttribLocation(...); vcol_location = glGetAttribLocation(...); to correct parameters written in fs and vs definition. I also had to modify stbi_load's last parameter to STBI_rgb_alpha to STBI_rgb. At this time texture looks like rendered but since thats a triangle I can just see lara croft's leg.